# The focal point vs. radius

Tags: geometry

I am trying to draw a parabolic dish on CAD. I've measured it to have a diameter of 149cm and a depth of 25cm. With this I calculated the focal point to be 55cm. Is the focal point the same as the radius (if I were to complete the parabolic dish into a sphere)? Or is that a different thing? If so, how do I find the radius?

EDIT1:
Picture of what I have
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot complete a parabolic dish into a sphere, the same way you can't complete a parabola into a circle. They are different objects. For this reason, “radius” in the sense used for spheres isn't applicable in your case.

What you can do, to get an idea of your shape, is to consider the 2D parabola that matches most of your measurements. Start at the origin, and then have the parabola pass through $\left(\pm \frac{149}2, 25\right)$.

Now where is the focus of this shape? You can best find it together with the directrix, since every point on the parabola has equal distance to both focus and directrix. Suppose the focus has coordinates $(0,\alpha)$, and the directrix has equation $y=-\beta$. Then the distance from the origin to the focus is $\alpha$ and from the origin to the directrix is $\beta$, so you can set $\alpha=\beta$. For the other defining points, you get

$$
\left(\frac{149}{2}\right)^2+(\alpha-25)^2 = (25+\beta)^2 = (25+\alpha)^2 \\
\alpha^2 - 50\alpha + \frac{24701}4 = \alpha^2 + 50\alpha + 625 \\
\alpha = \frac{22201}{400} = 55.5025
$$

So the focal length is almost the one you indicated in the center of your sketch. Also notice that the rim of the dish will be a lot farther away from the focus, namely $25+\alpha = 80.5025$.

So what is the equation of this parabola?

$$
x^2+(\alpha-y)^2 = (\alpha+y)^2 \\
x^2 - 2\alpha y + y^2 = 2\alpha y + y^2 \\
y = \frac{1}{4\alpha}x^2 = \frac{100}{22201} x^2
$$

If correct focal length is more important to you than the width and depth measurements, you can make $\alpha=55$ exactly in the above formula.

Here is an illustration, including the focal point and the directrix. For comparison, I've also included the circle through the two rim points and the origin, drawn in orange. It is close, but not equal.

[image: Illustration]

If exactness is not an issue for you, and the spherical approximation is close enough, you might still want to find the radius of that approximation. The center of the corresponding circle in the 2d image will be at $(0,r)$ and it will also satisfy

$$
\left(\frac{149}{2}\right)^2+(r-25)^2 = r^2 \\
r^2 - 50r + \frac{24701}4 = r^2 \\
r = \frac{24701}{200} = 123.505
$$